как изменить картинку в сообщении без path в aiogram
нужно сделать так, чтобы картинка в сообщении изменялась на новую картинку, сгенерированную с помощью Pillow, но так, чтобы не было сохранения самой картинки, как-нибудь через переменную, или.. можно ли вообще так сделать?
@router.callback_query(F.data == 'profile')
async def user_profile(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    await state.set_state(None)
    user_profile = main_func_bd('return_user_profile', user_id=callback.from_user.id)
    skin = user_profile[2]
    bg = user_profile[3]

    res_img = Image.open(rf'all_bg/bg/{bg}.png').convert('RGBA')
    skin = Image.open(rf'all_skins/skins/{skin}.png').convert('RGBA')

    res_img.paste(skin, (100, 100), skin)

    await bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, 
message_id=callback.message.message_id, 
media=res_img) <----


    byte_io = BytesIO()
    byte_io.name = 'image.png'
    res_img.save(byte_io, 'PNG')
    byte_io.seek(0)

    await bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id, media=InputMediaPhoto(media=BufferedInputFile(byte_io.read(), filename='image.png')))

надо бы изучить библиотеку byteio, а также узнать побольше aiogram...

если кто то знает еще какой то способ, напишите, пожалуйста... (как показала практика, мой способ не такой быстрый)

все всем спасибо, надо было просто сейвить не в png, а в jpeg, скорее всего это связано с тем, что телеграм поддерживает только jpg, и так как я сохранял в png, серверам приходилось конвертировать  из png в jpg и на это уходило около 1.5 секунд! (это моя догадка, тк все это основано на моей практике, если что то не так поправьте)

ты правильно мыслишь, телеграм всегда конвертирует в jpg. Еще автору вопроса рекомендую если он будет заранее подготовленные картинки отправлять, то записывать в словарь id картинок и по id отправлять. Так быстрее будет
